# How does an MVC System View element know when to update?

Tags: model-view-controller, theory

For example in AngularJS if you bind an `ng-model` to an `ng-repeater`, and your controller calls a service that updates the model, then the repeater is updated to reflect the change.

My question is, how does the view element (in this example, the `ng-repeater`) know to be updated?

For example, is there a timer that fires every couple milliseconds and updates the UI (unlikely)? Does the controller or view implement some type of internal event listener for all bindings and when the model updates, it fires a re-layout of the associated view elements?

Answer (score 1):

When we write an expression ({{dyanvar}}), behind the scenes Angular sets up a watcher on the scope model, which in turn updates the view whenever the model changes. This watcher is like any other watcher we set up in AngularJS:

```
$scope.$watch('dyanvar', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  //update the view with newValue
});
```

The second argument passed to $watch() is known as a listener function, and It is called whenever the value of dyanvar changes.

Your answer is in this article : 
https://cfdeepak.wordpress.com/2014/09/29/how-two-way-data-binding-works-in-angular-js/

Comment: Great find! I guess I was googling the wrong words for the question I actually had. Do you know if other MVC frameworks such as the .NET version work on similar concepts?

Comment: @chriszumberge 
Neither HTML nor JavaScript natively support data binding. This means that you have to write code to place data in a control and write code to extract it.
Or you can use frameworks that already do it for you. Most of the modern MVC frameworks do that for you and to name some : AngularJS, BackboneJS, Ember, Simpli5, Meteor and list goes on... 
Even there is a pulgin in Jquery to support the same : jQXB Expression.

Hope I was able to answer your question.

Comment: Right, that all makes sense, but since this is all mostly an MVC theory question than an angular-specific question, what about something not HTML/JS lik iOS development in Xcode? A UILabel's text is updated, does that framework also use a watcher? Like is a watcher the "MVC Framework Standard"?